# Compare unicode string with c ++ sign?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, utf-8

I want the result after comparing is 1 because the two strings are exactly the same, I don't understand why this is 0 and how to handle it?

```
string s1="\"Kilómetro 0,72\"";
s1=s1.substr(1,s1.length()-2);
cout<<s1<<endl;
string s2="Kilómetro 0,72";
cout<<s2<<endl;
if(s1==s2) cout<<1;
else cout<<0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your two strings are not the same. (Note the offset of the accent over `o` in `s2`.) This one works:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  string s1="\"Kilómetro 0,72\"";
  s1=s1.substr(1,s1.length()-2);
  cout<<s1<<endl;
  string s2="Kilómetro 0,72";
  cout<<s2<<endl;
  if(s1==s2) cout<<1;
  else cout<<0;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to compare returns true between string "Kilómetro 0.72" when removing quotes and the string Kilómetro 0.72? Thanks

Comment: @xuhdev Maybe I'm missing something, but your proposed code looks the same as the OP's problem code. But I [tested it](https://ideone.com/veaUJu) and it does produce a different result. Please elaborate why your answer works where the OP's code does not. Are you using different Unicode characters in your string literals?

Comment: @RemyLebeau OP's original version has a composite character in `s2` (**latin small letter o** + **combining acute accent**), the version above is simply **latin small letter o with acute**. Probably the answerer should have explained this rather than just posting mysteriously working code!

Comment: Note the "offset of the accent" is browser/font-dependent.  The OP's strings look the same in my browser.

Comment: @MarkTolonen same in mine, too

Answer (score 1):

Your strings are visually equivalent, but one uses ASCII `o` with combining accent (two Unicode code points U+006F,U+0301) and one uses `ó` (one Unicode code point U+00F3).

You need to [normalize](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/normalization) the strings using a library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) to compare them correctly, or at least with your example, type the combining character the same way in both string constants.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the end:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
    cout << (int)(unsigned char)s1[i] << " " << (int)(unsigned char)s2[i] << endl;
}
```

It will help you.

Comment: How to compare returns true between string "Kilómetro 0.72" when removing quotes and the string Kilómetro 0.72? Thanks